# How to ping-pong between parent and child processes in c on linux

Tags: c, linux, process, signals, ipc

I want my main process to create a pipe and a child process, than child send to pipe a number (starts with 0) and signals to parent, parent reads from pipe and if the number is less than 5, print it, increases it by 1 and pass it back by pipe and signals to child.

my problem is, i did not manage to sync them as a "ping-pong".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <unistd.h>

void parentSignal(int signum);
void  childSignal(int signum);

int pfd[2];
int fid, cid;
int val = 0;

void parentSignal(int signum){
    sleep(0);
    read(pfd[0], &val, sizeof(val));
    printf("my pid is: %d, X = %d\n",fid, val); val++;
    if (val==6) {
        puts("Parent is going to be terminated");
        kill(cid, SIGTERM); 
        kill(fid, SIGTERM);
    }
}
void childSignal(int signum){
    sleep(0);
    read(pfd[0], &val, sizeof(val));
    printf("my pid is: %d, Y = %d\n",cid, val); val++;
    if (val==6) {
        puts("Childd is going to be terminated");
        kill(cid, SIGTERM); 
        kill(fid, SIGTERM);
    }
}

int main(){

    if (pipe(pfd) < 0){ printf("Pipe Failed"); }

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {// We are in child   
        fid=getppid();  
        signal(SIGUSR1, parentSignal);
        write(pfd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
        kill(fid, SIGUSR1);
        while (1){
            sleep(0);
            write(pfd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
            kill (fid, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 0) {// We are in parent
        cid = pid;
        signal(SIGUSR1, childSignal);
        while (1){
            sleep(0);
            write(pfd[1], &val, sizeof(val));
            kill (cid, SIGUSR1);
        }
    }
    else { puts("Fork Failed !!"); }

    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);

return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me fix the code so the out put will be:

- 0
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- Child is going to be terminated
- Parent is going to be
  terminated

Comment: Shouldn't you be using two pipes? one for parent write/child read and another for communication the other way around? Just asking, didn't test either way...

Comment: I don't think that's my problem..

Comment: I finally tried it... no need for 2 pipes :) see https://pastebin.com/QLQEgECk

Comment: that's really nice man. but what i need must do the "ping-pong" throuh the "SIGUSR1".

Answer (score 0):

There are some timing issues from the example source.

Once either process writes to the pipe, there's no guarantee the other process will run and read from the pipe before the next iteration of the writer's while() loop.  A kill() request will post a signal to the target process and return; execution within the calling process continues and could again write() the same data to the pipe.  It's up to the system scheduler as to when any process [thread] gets dispatched and run.

BTW: note that sleep(0) should return immediately.

Generally a form a synchronization between processes is needed to reliably yield the described ping-pong sequence.  Example: after a process writes to the pipe, it could call something like sigsuspend(); the other calls read() followed by a kill() with a different signal to unblock the first process; maybe SIGUSR2, check for specific signal semantics on your target system.

Alternately, you could run 1 process with 2 threads and share a synchronization object; one idea might use pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_signal().

Comment: I will try those suggestions. if you wanna implement that I have no rejection :)